# Getting JWT access token from a webpage to python flask app

Tags: angular, python-3.x

I have created a web app in which each user is assigned a JWT accesstoken when they are logged in. This access token is used to make API calls. Once they log in this token object is passed to a javascript function. What this function does is that it saves the accesstoken in a localstorage variable. I am trying to integrate a Python Flask chatbot to this webapp (which is written in angular and Java backend). Once the user is logged in, that chatbot should be able to get the accesstoken, so that it call the API as well. But currently my chatbot is not able to call the api as it is not having the accesstoken. How can I pass the access token to my Flask chatbot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are making login functionality? Is the same java server is used to maintain that?

Comment: Yes, the java server maintains the login functionality. The chatbot comes up after logging into the webpage. I want the chatbot to get the accesstoken of the current session/login. It is stored in the localstorage as well in a variable called accesstoken.

Comment: I think, then cookies can help you. Your access token should be stored in cookies which will be passed with your request, whenever you will make http request to the server.